# MySQL installation problem

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm working on Windows with Apache and PHP.

I just installed MySQL, configured it, and started it.

But when I run

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

I don't see the `mysql` section, which means that I cannot use MySQL commands in the PHP code, right ?

Why is that ?

Should I do any manual connection between MySQL / PHP / Apache ?

Comment: why not use Wamp. It will do every thing automatically within few minuts

Comment: I'll go with Wamp ! Looks simple ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wamp is what I need !

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the MySQL module or Mysqli module in PHP. Find your php.ini or use your administrative console to turn one of them on. Then they should appear. Most distributions already include MySQL support. If you have built it yourself, you might need to recompile with the support turned on (but that is unlikely).

Comment: Thanks Jacob for your answer !

Answer (score -1):

Install XAMPP from http://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html.
Xampp install and setting up mysql, apache, php properly.